# How to make an overridable method repeat without getting StackOverflowException?

Tags: java, overriding

I'm creating a library in Java and need to have a method that repeats infinitely. It has to be overridable. I came up with something like this below, but I get `StackOverflowException`, which was predictable.

```
public void loop() {
  loop();
}

@Override
public void loop() {
  super.loop();
  //some stuff
}
```

Comment: *"need to have a method that repeats infinitely"* - why do you need such a thing?

Comment: This is recursion. You are unintentionally waking a devil as your stack keeps getting filled(StackOverflow)

Answer (score 1):

A method that calls itself indiscriminately is bound to raise a stack overflow error. Avoid this unwanted recursion and maybe use an infinite loop:

```
@Override
public void loop() {
    while(true) {
        super.loop();
    }
}
```

While the parent should just do whatever it's meant to do:

```
public void loop() {
  //do what is meant to do, not loop()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the work stuff out of your `loop` method into a separate method.

```
public void loop() {
   while (!condition) {
      doWork();
   }
}

protected abstract void doWork();



@Override
protected void doWork() {
   ....
}
```